# Vectorized OR function that evaluates FALSE | NA and NA | FALSE as FALSE?

Tags: r, logic, logical-operators

Given the vectors:

```
vect1 <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,NA,NA,TRUE,FALSE,NA,FALSE)
vect2 <- c(TRUE,NA,FALSE,NA,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,NA,TRUE,NA)
vect3 <- vect1 | vect2
vect3 #c(TRUE,NA,FALSE,NA,NA,TRUE,TRUE,NA,TRUE,NA)
```

Is there a vectorized infix function `x` that evaluates elements like this:

```
TRUE x TRUE #TRUE
TRUE x FALSE #TRUE
FALSE x TRUE #TRUE
FALSE x FALSE #FALSE
TRUE x NA #TRUE
NA x TRUE #TRUE
FALSE x NA #FALSE - would have been NA with ordinary "|"
NA x FALSE #FALSE - would have been NA with ordinary "|"
NA x NA #NA
```

Producing a vector `vect4` like this:

```
vect4 #c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,NA,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Or is there any other simple method to output `vect4` from `vect1` and `vect2`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compute the paralell maximum (with `na.rm = TRUE`) and convert to `logical`:

```
as.logical(pmax(vect1, vect2, na.rm = TRUE))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Note that by computing maxima of logical vectors, `TRUE` is interpreted as integer 1 and `FALSE` as integer 0.

Comment: Thanks, this is really concise!